# 9 million rows in my table that needs Address Scrubbed Is a CLR UDFSclar Function be better Than a SQL Server UDF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a performance question.  I need an Address Scrubbing routine.  My table has Almost 9,000,000 rows. Would a UDF in SQL Server with 80 Replace Commands VS a CLR Scalar Function VS a CLR Table Call VS a Web service Call to the POST office be more efficient?

Comment: Is the web-service call to the 3rd party service optional? Why do you have it is some variants and not in others?

Comment: I was trying to figure out if calling the Post Office Web service for standardizing the address might be more efficient than trying to code it myself for all the possible variants.  I think maybe Streaming a UD Table Function for 9,000,000 rows might be my best bet.

Comment: I don't think calling a web service 9m times is a particularly quick option.